# Как перезаписать данные в базу GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, graphql

```
const CREATE_POST_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation CreatePostMutation($firstName: String!, $lastName: String!) {
    createPost(firstName: $firstName, lastName: $lastName) {
      id
      firstName
      lastName
    }
  }
`
```

Я создаю запись в базу Graphcoll, как я могу перезаписать их по ID?

Answer (score 0):

```
const UPDATE_POST_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation {
  updatePost(
    id: "cjnvvo4kv055p01485hvydsvw"
    firstName: "This is the start of my biggest adventure!"
    lastName: "This is the start of my biggest adventure!"

  ) {
    id
  }
}
`
```